# Mark posts from mobile devices

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I occasionally post answers from my mobile, in the case a WP. Has any thought gone into marking questions and answers with a special symbol to signify they came from the mobile version of the site?

I did a quick search but couldn't find much. If such a feature exists, I'll be the first to delete this question and review my searching skills.

FYI this has been posted from a mobile device.

**Update (from a desktop):** my argument for such a feature is to set expectations on the possible formatting issues associated with a post. A post may be badly formatted, yet contain all the necessary information. It would then state that the poor quality could be assumed to be based on the limited input on a mobile device.

Were I to come back and flesh out the post on the full version of the site (assuming a laptop etc), then the marker could simply be removed.

As for the signal to noise ratio, this is opinionated. I see lots of noise when I'm prompted to share my posts over social networking sites.

Comment: Why does it need to be tagged as "sent from my mobile"? What is the use of that piece of information?

Comment: @Mat It is helpful to give an overview on possible quality issues with the post. Spelling, grammar, lack of code or code formatting, yet the answer may still be helpful or fleshed out at a later date. The specifics of the tag I have no idea about, I was thinking something a little more intuitive than a block of text ala emails, perhaps a simple mobile picture under the post votes. Make use of what is otherwise whitespace.

Comment: @balpha Declined without comment?

Comment: Mr. Dsappointments answer is spot-on. Posting from a mobile device is not an excuse for a bad answer. And if it's a good answer, there's no need for this.

Comment: @balpha It is a perfect excuse for questionable formatting, and formatting doesn't affect the content being conveyed, yet it affects a person's perception on the content. A marker from a mobile device sets expectation. Mr Disappoiment's answer doesn't even elude to the bad versus good debate - only an opinion on its noise and something about bragging.

Comment: @Adam: markdown formatting is essentially either whitespace or a few symbols. You don't need to do html-type tags. If your device can't handle `>` or spaces, and your post needs formatting to be useful, don't post from a mobile. (And using a mobile as an excuse for poor grammar or spelling is, really, ridiculous.)

Comment: @Mat perhaps the spelling, but typos and the special character sets being buried in strange places, not being able to amend per-character and other such mobile limitations that vary per-device, are all valid reasons that though the information is correct, the formatting or appearance of it is off. Poor perception on the appearance of the post then overtakes the actual content, rendering a perfectly correct answer downtrodden.

Answer (score 10):

> my argument for such a feature is to set expectations on the possible quality issues associated with a post.

That's a very good reason to *not* have such a feature. I don't see why it would be useful to encourage a lesser quality threshold for any reason. If anything, users should refrain from posting from mobile devices if they can't keep up with the usual quality standards.

If the only problem with the post is formatting, other users should step up and clean up. But you can't blame anyone for down voting, this is a Q&A site, rapid answers *may sometimes be* good, but good answers are always better.

Comment: So you would refuse to accept a valid answer that is otherwise information helping you for free based on the fact it insults your sensitivities towards not having a comma in the correct place?

Comment: @Adam I don't refuse anything, other than encouraging a lower quality threshold for posts posted via mobile devices. I try to edit and improve every post, other than the ones that I think it would be a waste of time. If there is a good answer in there, lacking only in formatting, I think most users will do the minor edits required. But actually _encouraging_ people to not care so much for the formatting of their posts, is a very bad idea.

Comment: But are rapid answers where the only fault is formatting worthy of a downvote? I don't think so, yet it occurs. This is my argument on setting expectation. If the mobile marker is visible, and my formatting is a little off but the information is rock solid, you could come along and edit. I argue some people would be more likely to do so knowing it originated from a mobile device than from a fully-fledged PC - if it was from a PC a first thought could be laziness.

Comment: @Adam `But are rapid answers where the only fault is formatting worthy of a downvote?` Sometimes they are. Call me a formatting nazi if you will, but I'm not a native English speaker and taking the time to properly structure & format your posts greatly helps me in understanding them.

Comment: It depends on how the formatting issue is taken. It is simple enough to put paragraphs or punctuation in place, however, visual formatting such as bold or italic text, headers etc, are not so simple - yet all contribute to the readability.

Comment: @Adam Of course it depends. We can't safely assume that mobile posts are downvoted just because of their formatting problems, as well. What we know is that mobile posts are more likely to have formatting issues, nothing more. But the feature adds no value whatsoever. If you feel your posts are downvoted _only_ because of their formatting issues, that's a problem that should be solved by encouraging people to edit and improve posts. I don't thing the feature you are proposing will do that, especially for visual formatting.

Comment: And such is the nature of feature requests. For me, I would see that symbol and be more lenient towards the post - assuming the actual answer is correct (there are plenty of instances where people blithely upvote an answer from a high-repped person when the answer itself is wrong) . It is highly likely this information is available already, and a small marker is not much extra on a site already showing lots of statistics regularly anyway.

Comment: @Adam Well, that's my point. I don't want people to be more lenient towards a post, for whatever reason. Assuming the answer is correct, I don't see why not wait until you can post from your PC. If someone beat you to it, well, so what?

Comment: The other side of the "beat you to it" coin is: I want to post now for the benefit of the OP, not for the benefit of my rep. But this is starting to get into a discussion on the mindset of voting habits, which is a can of worms at best. Whether through improper voting habits, social sheep herding, or actual impartial and factually based reasons - this feature has been downvoted anyway, so even if I see a use, others do not. Time to bow out.

Comment: @Adam Wasn't accusing you of rep farming. But answers appear rapidly on SO, and correct answers appear soon enough, so the OP benefits either way. If you have a correct answer and can post it, please do. And if you are getting downvoted all the time on correct answers with minor formatting issues, please post examples, that's a whole different issue.

Comment: I agree, and a mobile marker is not the entire solution, however I believed it had merit and was expecting a negative response. Don't worry, I don't take any of this personally.

Comment: @Adam Possible workaround would be a [user script for your mobile browser](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/06/02/run-greasemonkey-scripts-android-phone-tampermonkey/), one that would automatically add a marker to your answers. Something like "I'm posting this from my mobile, I'll come back and improve the post, but here's the quick answer"

Answer (score 4):

This makes little-to-no sense - is adds no value to the signal, but instead just noise.

The information might be useful at a statistical level, in terms of Stack Exchange monitoring traffic and device demographic, but that's *silent* data that they'll potentially have, and without a placeholder image/text to specify it.

Stack Overflow isn't the place to engage in bragging parties.

Comment: @MrDisappointment It is helpful to give an overview on possible quality issues with the post. Spelling, grammar, lack of code or code formatting, yet the answer may still be helpful or fleshed out at a later date. I have no idea where your point of bragging comes in. As for signal to noise, that is a UI issue and can be solved very cleanly with little "noise".

Comment: @MrDisappointment That is one of the reasons I state in the question from the mobile version of the site. A device, though mobile, may choose to run the full site and shouldn't be apart of such a feature.

Comment: Whether you run the full site, or stick with the mobile one on a mobile device, the 'problem' you state this would explain remains the same.

Comment: @MrDisappointment Yes but for frequent users of the site this would be a choice.